# Kinetic Typography ( After Effects / Cinema 4D )

Tags: typography

I would like to ask if anyone knows in which software these are done and if you know any tutorial that would help me learn this style. I am quite interested in typography and would love to play with this kind of style.

[Some sick kinetic type experiments](https://www.instagram.com/syddharth_mate/)

Comment: Why don't you ask the instagram user who created them?  Better to get it from the horses mouth rather than random guesses.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what you plan to output it to as some of this type of work can be done in CSS, HTML, JS these days.

The three big ones that come to mind are:

- Adobe After Effects
- Apple Motion
- Adobe Animate

Some would opt instead for 3D software which would likely be

- Cinema4D
- Maya

If you're looking to export to web then Adobe Animate would be the only software I'm familiar with. The rest of the HTML/CSS based kinetic typography projects are done strictly by coding, sometimes making use of javascript libraries such as anime.js.